# how to get array of objects based on conditions from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I would like to know how to compare array of objects and array based on conditions using javascript

for the given array of object `list` and array `arr1`, based on conditions

- if list `country` matches with `arr1`, return array object
- if list `country` not matches with `arr`, return array object

```
var result =  list.filter(mem => arr1.includes(mem));
```

```
var list =[
  {country:"IN", name: "john"},
  {country:"SG", name: "peter"}
  {country:"MY", name: "zen"}
]

var arr1=["IN", "YU"]
```

Expected Output

```
matched list
[
  {country:"IN", name: "john"},
  {country:"SG", name: "peter"}
]
not matched list
[
  {country:"MY", name: "zen"}
]
```

Comment: How is country "SG" put in the matched list?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use to use `filter` method two times:

```js
const list =[
  {country:"IN", name: "john"},
  {country:"SG", name: "peter"},
  {country:"MY", name: "zen"}
];
const arr1 = ["IN", "YU"];
const matched = list.filter((element) => arr1.includes(element.country));
const notMatched = list.filter((element) => !arr1.includes(element.country));

console.log('Matched List', matched);
console.log('Not Matched List', notMatched);
```

In the provided example, I'm assuming `arr1` contains the `country` property that needs to be present in the `country` attribute of matched elements, else all others are not matched.